# Codename One - WebBrowser is deprecated?

Tags: codenameone

I discovered a problem with WebBrowser scrolling on input field focus - once keyboard becomes open, WebBrowser scrolling not working any more. I started digging deeper and found... That WebBrowser is deprecated.

So, the question is 
**What should we use now instead of WebBrowser?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *BrowserComponent*.

*HTMLComponent* is deprecated, so *WebBrowser* is not needed any more.